# map.containsKey never worked in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I am doing an aggregation of the given objects based on some equal properties present in each.

```
final Map<JBlockedPerGT, JBlockedPerGT> ret = new HashMap<JBlockedPerGT, JBlockedPerGT>();

    while (allRows.hasNext()) {
        final JBlockedPerGT blockedPerGT = allRows.next();

        JBlockedPerGT updated = null;
        if (ret.containsKey(blockedPerGT)) {
            JBlockedPerGT current = ret.get(blockedPerGT);
            updated = current.add(blockedPerGT);
        } else {
            updated = blockedPerGT;
        }

        ret.put(updated, updated);
    }

    return ret.values().iterator();
```

It never gets into `if` condition and by that no aggregation has happened and each one treated as distinct object. The problem is, I did not understand it correctly how it is working. My `JBlockedPerGT` implemented the hashcode and equals method.

Can any one help me why I am not getting true in case of `ret.containsKey(blockedPerGT)` .

my hashcode and equals methods are

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 1;
    result = PRIME * result + ((gt == null) ? 0 : gt.hashCode());
    result = PRIME * result
            + ((messageType == null) ? 0 : Type.hashCode());
    result = PRIME * result
            + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
    result = PRIME * result
            + ((network == null) ? 0 : network.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    JBlockedPerGTImpl other = (JBlockedPerGTImpl) obj;
    if (gt == null) {
        if (other.gt != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!gt.equals(other.gt))
        return false;
    if (messageType != other.messageType)
        return false;
    if (country == null) {
        if (other.country != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
        return false;
    if (network == null) {
        if (other.network != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!network.equals(other.network))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: _My `JBlockedPerGT` implemented the hashcode and equals method._ Does it do so correctly? Does the `Map` actually contain the key?

Comment: Let's see your `equals()` and `hashCode()` method implementations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, As you said, might be map does not contains the key but don't know how this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `JBlockedPerGT` class does not honor the `hashCode` / `equals` contract.

Overriding the `hashCode` method of `Object` allows hashed collections to infer object equality.

Sine you are using a `HashMap` to store your `JBlockedPerGT`s as keys, it is crucial that `JBlockedPerGT#hashCode()` is overridden properly (and as a consequence, `equals` should be overridden too).

See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

**Edit**

Since you do have some `equals` / `hashCode` implementation in place, I would double-check the fields you are comparing / hashing and their real relevance in a test for equality (i.e. what if whatever you retrieve from persistence does **not** populate one of the fields by mistake or intentionally?).

I would also use a debugger and analyze the internals of the `JBlockedPerGT` objects retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're changing hash-generating attributes or equality-determining attributes in your `JBlockedPerGT` objects after using them as keys in the map.

It's best to implement map key objects as immutable. Otherwise you get into situations like this where you can't find a key in the map because its "identity" subsequently changed.